# Heroku "TypeError: o is not a function" issue when deploying Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I have a Rails app which works locally. When I deploy it to heroku and try to see it, the page is just white and in the dev console i see the error:

```
"TypeError: o is not a function
 at e (application-3cf416d1f738bfa0c9751b6f067d24ba462ae0d1fd10b7551c9f996491da5fbb.js:formatted:1134)
    at i (application-3cf416d1f738bfa0c9751b6f067d24ba462ae0d1fd10b7551c9f996491da5fbb.js:formatted:1085)
    at Object.merge (application-3cf416d1f738bfa0c9751b6f067d24ba462ae0d1fd10b7551c9f996491da5fbb.js:formatted:1137)
    at o.request (application-3cf416d1f738bfa0c9751b6f067d24ba462ae0d1fd10b7551c9f996491da5fbb.js:formatted:3919)
    at o.(/anonymous function) [as get] (https://syndicatorproto.herokuapp.com/assets/application-3cf416d1f738bfa0c9751b6f067d24ba462ae0d1fd10b7551c9f996491da5fbb.js:3:12554)
    at Function.get (application-3cf416d1f738bfa0c9751b6f067d24ba462ae0d1fd10b7551c9f996491da5fbb.js:formatted:2218)
    at n.value (application-3cf416d1f738bfa0c9751b6f067d24ba462ae0d1fd10b7551c9f996491da5fbb.js:formatted:8652)
    at er (application-3cf416d1f738bfa0c9751b6f067d24ba462ae0d1fd10b7551c9f996491da5fbb.js:formatted:12162)
    at Jn (application-3cf416d1f738bfa0c9751b6f067d24ba462ae0d1fd10b7551c9f996491da5fbb.js:formatted:11938)
    at Qn (application-3cf416d1f738bfa0c9751b6f067d24ba462ae0d1fd10b7551c9f996491da5fbb.js:formatted:11899)"
```

I have no idea what this error is does anyone have an idea ? Heroku logs don't show an error.

Comment: Have you tried running your app in production mode locally with precompiled assets. You seem to have an issue with javascript which is coming with precompiled version and skipped in development